# Start intent service and close app

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing GCM in my app and I start the RegistrationIntentService in the main activity.
What happens if I close the app before the intent finishes?

The service takes a few seconds and I need the registration finishes despite the user has closed the app.

This work this way or I have to do something more?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to see if it actually registers correctly? `IntentServices` are meant to run until it has finished its work and then quit so this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the system suddenly kills the application process, the intent will finish, because as a user you don't have direct control over when the app is actually closed (meaning, the process finished). When you "close" the app, you just put the activity in the background and the system will probably shut the process down some time later (see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/G_D3pKnGLt0)).

> I have to do something more?

So **no**, you should be fine with the standard `IntentService` - in normal cases it will finish even if the user "closes" the app, and in the case of system deliberately killing your process, there is nothing you can do about it anyway.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer! 
What I mean with "close" is go to list of opened apps and close it. We agree with this?

Comment: Removing the activity from recents is also not equivalent to shutting down the app process, so still no problem

Comment: Cool, please upvote my answer also if it helped.
And to clarify - an IntentService runs a separate thread underneath, and most times the only thing that could suddenly shutdown it's execution is, like I said, the kernel killing the whole process. So if you have a piece of code set to run - don't worry, it will.

Comment: I tried to upvote it but I have less of 15 reputation, sorry. Thanks again, it helped a lot.