# How to start / re-start IntentService when user kill the app

Tags: android, intentservice

I made an IntentService to search notifications in background when you start your phone and when you are in the app.
It's working, now I realized that when I kill the app (in the multitask), I don't receive new notifications anymore.

**Do you know how can I start (or restart) the IntentService when the user kill the app ?**

On the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524484/start-intent-service-and-close-app) it's told it's impossible but when I launch the Facebook's messenger app and kill it, I always can receive notifications !

PS : I'm using my web server to store notifications, I don't wan't to use an other way (like Google's solution) so save your time, and don't try to convert me :P

That's my code if it can help someone in the futur or you to understand :
*AndroidManifest.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fr.antoineduval.sortirauhavre">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="fr.antoineduval.sortirauhavre._MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="._MyService"
        android:exported="false"/>

</application>
```

*BroadcastReceiver* :

```
public class _MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, _MyService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

*IntentService* :

```
public class _MyService extends IntentService{

    private final int INTERVAL = 1000 ; // 1 sec

    private MyApplication application;
    private Timer timer;

    public _MyService(){
        super(_MyService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        this.application = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent){
        this.timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    check_notification();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, this.INTERVAL);
    }

    private void check_notification() throws IOException, JSONException {
        String url = MyApplication.NOTIFICATION_URL+"php/form/get.php?site="+MyApplication.NOTIFICATION_SITE_ID+"&last_notification_id="+this.application.get_cookie("last_notification_id");
        URL address = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = address.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        ArrayList<String> array = this.application.json_string_to_array(this.application.stream_to_string(is));
        for(int cpt = 0; cpt<array.size(); cpt++){
            String response = array.get(cpt);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

            int id = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("id"));
            String text = obj.getString("text");
            String title = obj.getString("title");
            String action = obj.getString("url");

            if(id > Integer.parseInt(this.application.get_cookie("last_notification_id")))
                this.application.set_cookie("last_notification_id", id+"");

            this.application.send_notification(title, text, id, action);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not confuse between the two things. Facebook has its own SDK which manages notification service . Just like for FCM you register it once and FCM library provides you callback methods,where you receive it.So frankly speaking Facbook notification mechanism is not depended mere on starting and stopping service. 
  For you try to use Service instead of intentService and in Service override onStart() command with return boolean variable return START_STICKY;
Though this is not advisable and totally safe, but it will work for most of the time till the kernel decides to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so to make sure I understand, you told me to transform my intentService to a service. I tried but when I did that, my notifications won't works. Are you sure I can make notifications with a simple service ?